# Temp Table not working inside a Cursor to store data

Tags: sql-server

Here is my cursor in side a stored Procedure

Using Temp table to store values inside the cursor

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM @AutoDataType 
OPEN cur    
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Customer_Id,@First_Name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN       
 If(NOT(@Customer_Id IS NULL))
     BEGIN
       Select * into #Temp_Auto from [dbo].[Auto] WHERE Customer_Id=@Customer_Id
 END                
  FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Customer_Id,@First_Name
END
CLOSE cur    
DEALLOCATE cur
Select * from #Temp_Auto
```

why i am getting Invalid Object Name #Temp_Auto ?
How to get the values into Temp table and return back

This is my parent table:

> ```
>  TranId   CustomerId CustomerName   Time_Stamp
>     1          11        aaa        2015-06-05 17:39:00
>     2          11        aaa        2015-06-05 17:45:00
>     3          12        bbb        2015-06-05 17:45:00
> ```

@AutoDataType contains CustomerId

> ```
>   CustomerID  CustomerName
>      11          aaa
>      12          bbb
> ```

what i want is get the records of customer based on id that to with Time_Stamp DESC [Latest entry]

Expected Table

> TranId  CustomerId CustomerName
>       2        11         aaa
>       3        22         bbb

Please guide me

This is my parent table:

> ```
>  TranId   CustomerId CustomerName   Time_Stamp
>     1          11        aaa        2015-06-05 17:39:00
>     2          11        aaa        2015-06-05 17:45:00
>     3          12        bbb        2015-06-05 17:45:00
>     4          11        aaa        2015-06-05 20:10:00
>     5          12        bbb        2015-06-05 20:10:00
> ```

@AutoDataType contains CustomerId

> ```
>   CustomerID  CustomerName
>      11          aaa
>      12          bbb
> ```

what i want is get the records of customer based on ID that to with Time_Stamp DESC [Latest entry]

Expected Table

> ```
> TranId  CustomerId CustomerName
>   4        11         aaa
>   5       22         bbb
> ```

Only 4 and 5 TranId because their Time_Stamp is latest one.

Comment: Why are you using a cursor here? Don't you already have this data as a copy in your table variable??? Of course if you have more than 1 row in @AutoDataType this will crash because the temp table already exists.

Comment: Then how can i selected rows on condtion and return back? Please suggest me

Comment: Are you expecting 1 row as your output with a dynamic number of columns? Are there any other details you have forgotten to mention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a cursor here is just the wrong way to go about this. You don't need another copy of the data, it is already in your table variable. All you need is a query to get the rows you want. You need to stop thinking about looping for everything. :D

```
select *
from
(
    SELECT a.CustomerID 
        , a.CustomerName
        , ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY CustomerID order by TIME_STAMP desc) as RowNum 
    FROM [dbo].[Auto] a
    JOIN @AutoDataType adt on adt.Customer_Id = a.Customer_Id
) x
where x.RowNum = 1
order by CustomerID
```

Comment: Please find the requirement in detail..  help me please

Comment: I added few more data to expalin it property.

Comment: The code I posted here will do exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Well I can't see the query you created but I suspect it is because the column name exists in both the table and the table variable. Prefix your columns with the alias and that should solve the problem. I almost always use the alias in my queries but for some reason did not here...I should have.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ... INTO creates a table with a definition to match the results of the select, then inserts into that table, thus you can only do that once for the given table.  If you really want to do the above, you need to create #Temp_Auto outside the loop, then INSERT into it rather than SELECT ... INTO.

That being said, why would you even bother with the cursor?  Given your code it's completely unnecessary and will perform pretty poorly compared to the alternatives.  Why not just select all the rows from dbo.Auto that have a Customer_Id in @AutoDataType and insert those into the temp table?